# How to get dimensions in dp correctly for android?

Tags: android, text, size

I am trying to create `textView` programatically, but I am unable to `setTextSize` without any issues.

```
textViewMessage.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.main_stripe_small_text));
```

So, I am trying to get dimensions from dimen file (15dp), but it when `textView` is displayed, text is much larger. When changing line to this:

```
textViewMessage.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15);
```

everything is displayed like it should be. Any ideas?

Comment: textViewMessage.setTextSize(15f);

Comment: @AlexChengalan I want to get dimensions properly - from dimensions drawable.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels

Comment: @PadmaKumar tried it, text gets even bigger by using this method.

Comment: log the value of getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.main_stripe_small_text) and first set to on float value then use float in setText method and check

Comment: Tried to get main_stripe_small_text as float, it should be 15, but I got 22.5. Why is that? Dimension is defined as: `<dimen name="main_stripe_small_text">15dp</dimen>`

Answer (score 2):

`textViewMessage.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,` `getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.main_stripe_small_text));`

//you are setting  `R.dimen.main_stripe_small_text` as `15dp`

when you are reading is will give you `22.5px for hdpi and 30px for xhdpi`

again you are trying to do `textViewMessage.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 22.5px);`

now you will get `33.75px for hdpi and 45px for xhdpi`

**Solu:**

you need to put 15px in your `R.dimen.main_stripe_small_text`

or

just set textsize as

```
`textViewMessage.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.main_stripe_small_text));
```

Comment: `textViewMessage.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.main_stripe_small_text));` - this still made the text too big...

Comment: RU declared this in R.dimen.main_stripe_sma‌​ll_text in any other values folder? Make sure that you need to declare only in Values folder.

Comment: It has been declared only in values folder dimens.xml

Comment: what size you want? declare as 15px in your dimension value. which device you are testing?

Comment: Defining as 15px works, but that is not "a neat job", since all of the values should be in dp. I don't like bad programming habbits.
I want it to be 15dp.

Comment: what size you want? and which device you are getting toooo big?

Comment: I already said what size I want text to be. Currently testing on samsung galaxy s2, but that is really not that important now is it?